# Display tool tip when scrollbar is scrolled using mouse in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, scrollbar, mouse, tooltip

I am making an web application using silverlight 3.0 . In that application i have one scroll bar. Whenever i am scrolling the scrollbar using , i want to show the corresponding scroll value as a tool tip. I am not getting how to do that. Please help me.Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch the scroll event of scrollbar in any load event

```
        ScrollBar vertical = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer1, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
        vertical.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(vertical_ValueChanged);
```

Then the following event handler will show the tooltip. If you want to access tooltip elsewhere, make it global. You can also set its IsOpen property to false when you dont want to display.
EDIT: you have to make the tooltip global

```
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    void vertical_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        tt.IsOpen = false;
        tt.Content = e.NewValue;
        tt.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Hope this Helps.!